# Video Thumbnail loading slow in android

Tags: android, gridview, video-thumbnails

Hi here I create an app for video play. In which I use gridview for Video which contain thumbnail and title of video.
But it takes too much time for load and when it loaded in gridview it also problem with swipe(slow).
Here is my code

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<AllVideoModel> allVideoList;
AllVideoListAdapter adapter;
GridView gridView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    allVideoList = listVideo(MainActivity.this);
    adapter = new AllVideoListAdapter(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this, allVideoList);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public ArrayList<AllVideoModel> listVideo(Context context) {
    ArrayList<AllVideoModel> allVideoModelsList = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA};
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
            null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            AllVideoModel model = new AllVideoModel();
            String videoPath = c.getString(0).toString();
            String videoTitle = videoPath.substring(videoPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            model.setVideoTitle(videoTitle);
            model.setVideoPath(videoPath);
            allVideoModelsList.add(model);
        }
        c.close();
    }
    return allVideoModelsList;
  }
}
```

> AllVideoListAdapter

```
public class AllVideoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<AllVideoModel> allVideoModelArrayList;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public AllVideoListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AllVideoModel> allVideoModelArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.allVideoModelArrayList = allVideoModelArrayList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return allVideoModelArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

private class Holder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView text;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder = new Holder();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout_video, parent, false);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(allVideoModelArrayList.get(position).getVideoPath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
   /* ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("", holder.image,
            DisplayImageOption.getDisplayImage(),
            new AnimateFirstDisplayListener());*/
    holder.text.setText(allVideoModelArrayList.get(position).getVideoTitle());
    return convertView;
  }
}
```

> AllVideoModel

```
public class AllVideoModel {
String VideoTitle, VideoPath;

public String getVideoTitle() {
    return VideoTitle;
}

public void setVideoTitle(String videoTitle) {
    VideoTitle = videoTitle;
}

public String getVideoPath() {
    return VideoPath;
}

public void setVideoPath(String videoPath) {
    VideoPath = videoPath;
  }
}
```

I thought that it should be resolve through cache thumbnail but I can't get it.

Comment: try universal image loader library for load thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

Some points for optimisation:

- if your app uses `CursorAdapter` instead of `BaseAdapter+ArrayList` it is not neccessary any more to load all grid items in advance but only those that are visible. This is important if you have many videos on your device.
- if you use `MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail` instead of `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail...)` android can do thumb creation and caching for you.

I have done something similiar for photos. see https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/blob/FDroid/app/src/main/java/de/k3b/android/androFotoFinder/gallery/cursor/GalleryCursorAdapter.java for details

Comment: Thanks for answering I checked above link but cant get understand that how to use it. I tried it with Universal Image Loader but it still take time to load thumbnail while i enable cacheInMemory(true) and cacheInDisk(true) as well.
And MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail method tried but unable to implement it.